# jquery svg paths: clicking path B check if path A is currently active, if so deactivate A and activate B

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, svg, path

First of all, thanks for your interest.
I've got this SVG (country map), and I want the user to click an area of that map so that a div with information about that area pops up and that area (SVG) gets a new color('active'). 
If the user clicks again on that area, it will get it's previous state and div will hide. So far, so good.

The problem is, if an area is currently 'active' (e.g Area A) and the user clicks another area(e.g Area B), both Areas will be active, and I'd like Area A to deactivate.

So far this is my code:

```
$(function (){
            $('.distrito').on('click', function(){
                if ( $(this).hasClass( 'distrito' ) ) {
                    $(this).removeClass('distrito').addClass('distritoIsActive');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('distritoIsActive').addClass('distrito');
                }
/*this will get corresponding div to showup*/
                $('#legenda' + this.id).toggle(1000);
            });
        });
```

I think I should loop through paths searching for the distritoIsActive class, and I did and created an array with all areas:

```
let $svgObject = document.getElementById('Layer_1');
let $myDistrictos = Array.from($svgObject.querySelectorAll("path"));
```

But I'm not able to loop through the array so the app will know if there's a distritoIsActive class and pass it to my function.
Can someone help me please? 
Thanks in advance

You can find sample code here: 
[http://mapa.e-forma.pt/](http://mapa.e-forma.pt)

Comment: Can you create a working example (something minimal) that shows the issue?

Comment: If only one thing can be active, use a global and store the active element in it.

Comment: Answering @Dekel:
Sure I've uploaded some sample code. You can find it here:
http://mapa.e-forma.pt/ 
Sorry I didn't do that in first place.

Comment: Answering @ Robert Longson: Hi, thanks for your help, but not sure if I understood that. Could you give me some example?

Comment: @FroPT explain what do to and what is the issue. (I click on this/click on that/expecting A/B/C). You can also add a gif-animation of the issue.

Comment: @Dekel, If an area (e.g. Area A) is clicked, that area changes colour(red) and a div(div A) is shown. If you click another area (e.g. Area B) Area A gets previous colour and div A hides, Area B gets new colour and div B is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a simple check in your code to get to what you wanted. Have a look below (just the js part)

```
let $svgObject = document.getElementById('Layer_1');
let $myDistrictos = Array.from($svgObject.querySelectorAll("path"));
let previous = null;

/*let $redClassIsActive = false;*/
console.log($myDistrictos);

$(function (){
        $('.distrito').on('click', function(){

        if(previous === null)
        {
          $(this).removeClass('distrito').addClass('distritoIsActive');
          $('#legenda' + this.id).toggle(1000);
          previous = this;
          return;
        }



        if(previous !== null && previous.id === this.id)
        {
        previous = null;
        $(this).removeClass('distritoIsActive').addClass('distrito');
        $('#legenda' + this.id).toggle(1000);
        }
        else
        {
        $(previous).removeClass('distritoIsActive').addClass('distrito');
        $('#legenda' + previous.id).toggle(1000);
        $(this).removeClass('distrito').addClass('distritoIsActive');
        $('#legenda' + this.id).toggle(1000);
        previous = this;

        }


        });
    });
```

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks Mpho! You nailed it. I was trying to do with $redClassIsActive what you did with var previous. Some kind of flag. Thanks for your help!! :)
And a big thank you to all the community!

Comment: Hi Mpho, actually it's not still correct. But that's north for me. Look what happens when you select an area twice. I've uploaded your code to same url: http://mapa.e-forma.pt/

Comment: Hi FropT, sorry for the previous solution with a bug. I was still at work when I rushy did it. See the updated code sample, it should solve your problem 100%.

Comment: Hi Mpho! Thank you so much for helping me. I've been working like a dog, therefore I really appreciate the time you spent on helping me. You rock as a coder and as a fellow! Big thanks bro :)

Comment: No problem Bro. It was a fun task to do nonetheless. I'm glad you found a solution